# RestKit: add relationship connection to the certain NSManagedObject when mapping another NSManagedObject

Tags: core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I've got two entities: `Order` and `OrderInfo`, both of them are `NSManagedObject` subclasses. `OrderInfo` has got a relationship `order`.

Now, I've already got a certain `Order` instance in my managed object context (let's call it `myOrder`), and I want to load `OrderInfo` that corresponds to `myOrder` from server.

How should I instruct RestKit to fill `order` relationship property of `OrderInfo` with `myOrder` during mapping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a technique called [foreign key mapping](http://restkit.org/api/latest/Classes/RKConnectionDescription.html). You need to have unique identifiers on each of the objects (well, at least the existing one you need to find in the data store) and then you tell RestKit about the relationship to populate, the identity key of the target and the identity key of the value in your received data to match against.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution. But what if I haven't got `orderId` property in `OrderInfo` response?

Comment: Then you have a problem. How do you know which one to connect to? You need some information to base the connection on.

Comment: well, I know for which order I request order info, so what I'm searching is a way to manually set the relationship during mapping.

Comment: worst case, you can manually connect the order and the info objects from the mapping result in the success block. I guess you're doing a `getObjectsAtPath` for the info objects? None of the GET methods use the source object for the mapping, just for path creation...

Comment: Is there a way do connect it BEFORE RestKit actually saves context, so that this relationship could be non-optional?

Comment: Foreign key mapping, which in your case means editing the deserialized data just before the mapping begins to inject the id to connect to...